# iOS Gmail API - Sample code to retrieve Gmail messages for a given label in Swift 4 / Xcode9

Tags: gmail-api, ios11, swift4, xcode9

first question for me on stackoverflow.com so hopefully I am doing it correctly!

I currently have the following code (Xcode 9 / Swift 4) using the example provided in the [Gmail API web site](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ios?ver=swift) which works fine:

```
let query = GTLRGmailQuery_UsersMessagesList.query(withUserId: "me")
service.executeQuery(query,
                         delegate: self,
                         didFinish: #selector(displayResultWithTicket2(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:))
```

However instead of retrieving all emails for "me", I just want to retrieve the emails for a given label. Google has an example [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) in its API reference where one of the parameters can be a label but unfortunately I cannot find the equivalent Swift code. They "only" cover: Java, .Net, Php, Python and Javascript.

My question is about: how do you code this in Swift? The method above "GTLRGmailQuery_UsersMessagesList.query" only accepts a User Id.

Alternatively the [example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) mentions the use of HTTP request and parameters (in particular "q"), can I use that in Swift and how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my, it was soooo simple! After the first line of code (let query...), you just need to call the properties of "query", e.g.

```
let query = GTLRGmailQuery_UsersMessagesList.query(withUserId: "me")
query.q = "is_unread"
service.executeQuery(query,
                         delegate: self,
                         didFinish: #selector(displayResultWithTicket2(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:))
```

Lots to learn for me! But hopefully that will be useful to someone!

Comment: thanks Christope, not exactly what I was looking for but your code has helped point me in the right direction. The docs of the gmail api for swift is practically non existent and very poor.

Comment: Glad it helped somehow!

Comment: So i'm stuck on this again. Basically how do I authorize the GTLGMailService with an token for api calls within the readonly scope. seen a lot of code samples but they're all Obj c. I want an example in a Swift project. I also need to see an explanation on GTMAppAuth library also in swift

Comment: The call i make to the GTLRGmailQuery_UsersMessagesList.query result in an error saying Login Required. How did you build and authorization method for this solution?

Comment: Hi, I am sorry but I did this two years ago so I am not sure anymore and I cannot access my source code anymore. The only thing I seem to remember was that Google had a "starter kit" also for Swift which I used initially for the login process. Maybe search in this direction again?